# How to slice pandas dataframe geolocation

Tags: python, pandas

I have read in a bunch of data into my dataframe (df) from a CSV file.
One of the fields is a GeoLocation (longitude, latitude) and I wish to slice out certain rows where the longitude is between 37 and 40.
The CSV stores the geolocation in a column with (longitude, latitude)
I am having trouble using the 'df.where()' function

```
geo = df.where(df['GeoLocation'][0] < 40 & df['GeoLocation'][0] > 37)
```

This keeps throwing error saying

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What am i doing wrong when i am trying to slice the column?

Here is the code i used to pull in the data

```
df = pd.concat([x for x in pd.read_csv('U.S._Chronic_Disease_Indicators__CDI_.csv', chunksize=1000)], ignore_index=True)'
```

Comment: I'd separate out the geolocation values into separate columns and convert to numeric if possible so you can do `df[(df['longtitude'] > 37) & (df['longtitude'] < 40)]`

Comment: In addition to the other comments/answers addressing the requirement to place the conditions in parentheses, check the dtypes of the columns since it sounds like it's trying to compare a string to your values of 40 and 37. Use `df['GeoLocation'].dtype`. It's either an object containing tuples, or it could be a column of strings. I would break the `GeoLocation` column into two columns: one for lat and one for long.

Comment: @3novak the df['GeoLocation'].dtype said "method object is not subscriptable"

And when i did  df.where(df['GeoLocation'].str.get(0).between(37,40, inclusive=False))
it threw an "AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'where'. 

I can't make sense what is going on since df should be a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You want to split up the series first, then do a filter

```
df[['lat', 'long']] = df['GeoLocation'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
geo = df[(df['lat'] < 40) & (df['long'] > 37)]
```

Note that the [(x) & (y)] is *very* picky about you explicitly having all the parentheses.